# CKReference change to nil is not reported in CKFetchRecordChangesOperation

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have set a custom zone in private database to store records and fetch changes to keep a local cache on the device. All works fine if a string value or number value is changed from one device it is fetched when CKFetchRecordChangesOperation is triggered on another device, but if a ckReference is set to nil and saved from one device it is saved successfully on the CloudKit Servers.

Now when the second device fetches changes using CKFetchRecordChangesOperation the record is fetched but CKRecord's keys doesn't have the key for the CKReference property which changed instead it has the name key of String type which I didn't change on the record.